# Is there a way to optimise this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not very good with HTML and but I'm trying to make a website that will load Discord servers the user is in. I got the servers in map format, but loading them is very slow. Is there a way the time could be reduced? Any help is greatly appreciated!

**My HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>NULL MUCH?</title>
<style>
    .server {
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        object-fit:cover;
        border-radius:50%;
    }
    .serverImgIn {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        object-fit:cover;
        border-radius:50%;
        border-color: rgb(0, 89, 190);
    }

    .serverImgOut {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        object-fit:cover;
        border-radius:50%;
        cursor: pointer;
        filter: grayscale(100%);
    }

    .serverRow {
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- PLACEHOLDER TEXT HERE -->
    </div>

    <script>
        window.onload = () => {
            const guilds = {the guilds in JSON format}

            var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
            
            var row = document.createElement("servers_row");
            row.innerHTML = ""; // clear images
            row.classList.add('serverRow');

            for (let i = 0; i < guilds.length; i++) {
                //New row every 10 servers
                if (i % 10 == 0) {
                    wrapper.appendChild(row);
                    row.innerHTML = "";
                    row.classList.add('serverRow');
                }

                var div = document.createElement("div");
                var imagem = document.createElement("img");
                var name = document.createElement("p");
                name.innerText = guilds[i].name;

                if (guilds[i].icon) {
                    imagem.src = `https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/${guilds[i].id}/${guilds[i].icon}.png`;
                } else {
                    imagem.src = 'http://purepng.com/public/uploads/large/purepng.com-white-cloudnaturestylenaturalbeautifulgreen-5415211264555x7ih.png';
                }

                if (guilds[i].inServer) {

                    //OPEN A NEW WINDOW FOR SERVER EDITING
                    imagem.onclick = function() {
                        imagem.classList.add('serverImgIn');
                        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.open('post', 'http://localhost:53134/getServer/', true);
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('guilds', JSON.stringify(owned));
                        xhr.onloadend = (e) => { window.localStorage.setItem('serverInfo', (JSON.stringify(xhr.response))); window.location = 'http://localhost:53134/dashboard.html'; }
                        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(owned));
                    }
                } else {
                    imagem.classList.add('serverImgOut');
                    imagem.onclick = function() {
                        window.open('DISCORD INVITE LINK HERE');
                    }//OPEN A NEW WINDOW WITH SERVER INVITE

                }

                div.appendChild(imagem);
                div.appendChild(name);

                div.classList.add('server');

                row.appendChild(div);
            }

            wrapper.appendChild(row);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

As a note I'm not sure if adding the `onclick` function in the loop increases the time, because It's not actually being called.

This is what it looks like on my end but to test it I think you'll have to pass in dummy data (I use the Discord API to get my data)
[image: What it looks like]

Comment: Could be worth it to ask on the [CodeReview stack exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: post guilds example to help us make a better test